# Admin add editor field and widget?

Tags: admin, widgets, adminform, widget

I have a custom module. Inside _prepareForm I have also field editor.

```
$wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array('add_variables' => false, 'add_widgets' => true,'files_browser_window_url'=>$this->getUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/'));
$fieldset->addField('my_field_name','editor',array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Some text'),
            'name' =>  'my_field_name',
            'config'    => $wysiwygConfig,
            'required'=>true,
            'style'=>'width:400px;height:300px;'
));
```

I can insert widget inside editor and when I press Save, it is still proper recognized. But when I call that field value inside template

```
 $myobject->getData('my_field_name')
```

it will show

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="1"}}
```

instead of actual widget content.

How does Magento parse data if widget is inside, how can I show this widget once it was inserted inside editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting `my_field_name` will return you raw content from the database. You have to pass it through CMS processor:

```
echo Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($myobject->getData('my_field_name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Block file you can override the _toHtml method. It is the magento filter static block and cms pages content :

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $html = parent::_toHtml();
    return Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($html);
}
```

In this way it will process all your content.
See in these files :

```
Mage_Cms_Block_Page
Mage_Cms_Block_Block
```